# Pivot table widget in icCube - hover to show same information as in IDE

Tags: properties, mdx, iccube

In the icCube MDX IDE, you can hover over a member and you will get the information for this member, such as:

- name
- key
- uniqueName

and
- properties, such as ic3Color, or custom defined ones.

In the Pivot table you can display member information using functions like getMDXUName, getName and getLevelDepth (see [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/viz/doc/viz11PivotTableII.php)).

Is it also possible to show the member property?

If this is possible, you can make a hover going over a member that allows to show additional details for it.

Applications:
- hover over an invoice number, showing properties such as invoice date, description, url to document
- hover over a project, showing properties as manager, start date, end date
- etcetera